# SQL: If var = '' do nothing else add a condition to a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, if-statement, where-clause

I would like to perform one part of a WHERE clause on the condition that a variable has a value. I have tried writing this in many different ways but always hit an error and was wondering if someone could help.

The code below is my current SQL statement that works but will return nothing if my @itemId is empty. I would only like to reduce the results if the @itemId as a value.

```
DECLARE @itemId nvarchar(max)
SET @itemId = 'someId'

SELECT
SalesOrdersItems.Id,
CASE
    WHEN SalesOrderItems.ItemType = 'P' THEN Products.ProductId
    WHEN SalesOrderItems.ItemType = 'S' THEN Sundries.SundryId
    WHEN SalesOrderItems.ItemType = 'F' THEN FreightMethods.FreightMethodId
    ELSE SalesOrderItems.FreeTextItem
END AS ItemId
FROM SalesOrderItems
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Products ON SalesOrderItems.Product = Products.Product
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sundries ON SalesOrderItems.Sundry = Sundries.Sundry
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FreightMethods ON SalesOrderItems.FreightMethod = FreightMethods.FreightMethod
WHERE 
SalesOrdersItems.area LIKE 'SE%'
AND (Products.ProductId = @itemId OR Sundries.SundryId = @itemId OR FreightMethods.FreightMethodId = @itemId OR SalesOrderItems.FreeTextItem = @itemId)
```

I have tried writing the last line like this(see code below) but it doesn't work.

```
AND CASE 
        WHEN @itemId = '' THEN 1
        ELSE (Products.ProductId = @itemId OR Sundries.SundryId = @itemId OR FreightMethods.FreightMethodId = @itemId OR SalesOrderItems.FreeTextItem = @itemId)
    END
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason OR won't suit your needs?  AND (@itemID = '' OR (...))

Comment: wont fix the problem, but consider using an alias names for your tables it can help reduce clutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm misunderstanding please let me know, I'm assuming that if you have a blank @itemID you want all results, otherwise you'll limit the results.

```
WHERE SalesOrdersItems.area LIKE 'SE%' 
AND ((@itemId != '' 
    AND (Products.ProductId = @itemId 
         OR Sundries.SundryId = @itemId 
         OR FreightMethods.FreightMethodId = @itemId 
         OR SalesOrderItems.FreeTextItem = @itemId)) 
    OR @itemId = '')
```

I believe I have the parens correct, but they might be uneven. Hopefully it is it clear enough to understand my intent.

Comment: +1 This is the way I would initially lean.  Some optimizers are even smart enough to be able to optimize away the excluded conditions...

Answer (score 2):

```
...
WHERE
1 = CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [`NULLIF()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#NULLIF)

```
AND CASE 
        WHEN NULLIF(@itemId, '') IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE (Products.ProductId = @itemId OR Sundries.SundryId = @itemId OR FreightMethods.FreightMethodId = @itemId OR SalesOrderItems.FreeTextItem = @itemId)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you should do something like below.

```
     (Products.ProductId = @itemId OR ISNULL(@itemId, '') = '') OR 
     (Sundries.SundryId = @itemId OR ISNULL(@itemId, '') = '') OR 
     (FreightMethods.FreightMethodId = @itemId OR ISNULL(@itemId, '') = '') OR 
     (FreightMethods.FreeTextItem = @itemId OR ISNULL(@itemId, '') = '')
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This appears to be the SQL Server brand of host parameters (with which I am not familliar).  Is it possible to use `OR @itemId IS NULL` instead?  Just curious.  Also, it should be possible to extract the `@itemId` clause, so it only has to be checked once.